# Wordpress - How to create new page (also template page for that) using plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

How to create new page and its template page using wordpress plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress 3.4.2, I'm using the plug in named "DX Page Template". The link is at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dx-template-manager